# Adding Password to Logon message with QuickFix

Tags: python, quickfix, fix-protocol

Hi there I am having issues with Quick Fix python. I need to add Tag 554 to my outbound Logon message to send messages in to the exchange as it is required but I am unsure how to go about this. All the online examples I find are C++ code and my attempts to translate those to Python are not successful.

If someone could advise how to send Logon messages out with a password tag it would be appreciated:

```
 def toAdmin(self, sessionID, message):
        message.getHeader().setField(554, "password")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks close to correct.  You didn't actually say what happens you run it, so I can't be 100% sure what you think is wrong with it.

But there is one improvement that is needed:  You only want to set the password on Logon messages.

```
def toAdmin(self, sessionID, message):
        if message.getHeader().getField(35) == "A":
                message.getHeader().setField(554, "password")
```

(Forgive any Python syntax errors; it's not a language I know well.)

This is very similar to what you'd do in any other QF port.  For instance, see the [QuickFIX/n User FAQ](https://github.com/connamara/quickfixn/wiki/User-FAQ) for the C# way.